How to convert stairs climbed to distance walked, based on energy spent?
I built an exercise step for my tiny apartment. I do a couple hundred steps at a time which gets my heart pumping. I am guessing that the ratio of stairs climbed to distance is about 1x stair to 3x feet/ 1x metre of walking on a flat surface - is this correct?
Is there a better way to convert stairs climbed into distance walked on a flat surface?
